# Error 101 Server Did Not Report Size from OTA Upgrade framework via git hub

Tags: web, ota

I have tried [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FuY6BobS-1k):

[ESP8266 Self Update OTA from GitHub](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FuY6BobS-1k)

Instruction and made [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/soheilpaper/ota_github_blink):

And changed [the main code](https://github.com/programmer131/ESP8266_ESP32_SelfUpdate/blob/master/esp8266_ota/esp8266_ota.ino) to [this type](https://github.com/soheilpaper/ota_github_blink/blob/main/ESP_OTA_Github.ino), but I get this error:

```
HTTP_UPDATE_FAILD Error (-101): Server Did Not Report Size
```

[image]
when the    `FirmwareUpdate();` code is running.
So I don't know why GitHub don't answer to the esp8266, as said [here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/5131):

> The error has nothing to do with your sketch. Also, the error code is
> not a HTTP 101 error. The problem is that your server does not send
> the response header 'Content-Length'

I have some dupt about the bin URL file address which have many dot on the end of it (`https://github.com/soheilpaper/ota_github_blink/blob/main/BlinkWithoutDelay.ino.esp8285.bin`) on it, could it be the reason for none answering and giving the 101 code form GitHub server!

Any suggestion would be good help to fix this bug.

**Update 1:**

> I have changed the bin file name to this kind :
>
> ```
>  BlinkWithoutDelay.ino.esp8285.bin  ---->      BlinkWithoutDelay_ino_esp8285.bin
> ```
>
> But I have again the same GitHub 101 error.

**Update 2:**

Based on the [timemage](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/70020/timemage) answer, I have changed the address of `bin` and `TXT` file by finding the download link of those files form the GitHub. And it has been working by changing the `blob` part of address to `raw`, so the bin address changed form `https://github.com/soheilpaper/ota_github_blink/blob/main/BlinkWithoutDelay_ino_esp8285.bin` to `https://github.com/soheilpaper/ota_github_blink/raw/main/BlinkWithoutDelay_ino_esp8285.bin` And the `https://github.com/soheilpaper/ota_github_blink/blob/main/version.txt`to  `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/soheilpaper/ota_github_blink/main/version.txt`

And now that error has been fixed as you can see below:

[image]

Although I gave some dupt about upgrading the main code by getting this output via serial port:

```
Device already on latest firmware version
```

And I would check it after some resting!.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question seems to contain its own answer, so I'm confused.  Do you understand what the Content-Length header is?

Comment: please, no picture of text ... it is unreadable ... post the actual text

Comment: @timemage, I don't know how can I get this information via the [main code](https://github.com/soheilpaper/ota_github_blink/blob/main/ESP_OTA_Github.ino)!

Comment: @jsotola, there is not s information via serial port output, the main part of it is the **101 error** type by this output : `HTTP_UPDATE_FAILD Error (-101): Server Did Not Report Size
`

Comment: If `Device already on latest firmware version` is a problem, and it's not clear that it is, it is probably the subject of a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ESP8266httpUpdate library [wants to know in advance](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/2.7.4/libraries/ESP8266httpUpdate/src/ESP8266httpUpdate.cpp#L293) how large the file is before it starts downloading it.  It wants to know this so it can tell, before trying to download (and program), [whether or not there's enough space](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/2.7.4/libraries/ESP8266httpUpdate/src/ESP8266httpUpdate.cpp#L326) for it. If the size of the file isn't provided by the server it will [report the error](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/2.7.4/libraries/ESP8266httpUpdate/src/ESP8266httpUpdate.cpp#L418) that you are seeing.

The size of the file is provided by the web server by means of the [Content-Length](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.13) HTTP response header [read by HTTPClient](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/2.7.4/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient/src/ESP8266HTTPClient.cpp#L1361).  This header is received in advance of the file content.

Your main code appears to contain a correct link to raw .bin file,
`#define URL_fw_Bin "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/programmer131/otaFiles/master/firmware.bin"`, and reports the following headers:

```
cache-control: max-age=300
content-security-policy: default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'; sandbox
content-type: application/octet-stream
etag: "b2ecfb5dc91587c089acdaace446b0d7b00863c9f42dffb36c7983c103d3a98a"
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: deny
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.0), 1.1 varnish
x-github-request-id: 8728:2B67:9AFD3:AD0EC:6008FCFF
accept-ranges: bytes
date: Thu, 21 Jan 2021 04:03:32 GMT
x-served-by: cache-bos4651-BOS
x-cache: MISS, HIT
x-cache-hits: 0, 1
x-timer: S1611201812.154162,VS0,VE1
vary: Authorization,Accept-Encoding
access-control-allow-origin: *
x-fastly-request-id: bfc9702929b91be55d7aa040465a230436918e01
expires: Thu, 21 Jan 2021 04:08:32 GMT
source-age: 20
content-length: 270016
```

The **content-length: 270016** at the bottom shows that this should work.  But your changed code that uses `#define URL_fw_Bin "https://github.com/soheilpaper/ota_github_blink/blob/main/BlinkWithoutDelay_ino_esp8285.bin` is to the HTML page for downloading the file, which does **not** report `Content-length`, for me anyway, but then it's the wrong URL anyway.

Regarding the "101 error", it's `-101` (negative) [defined here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/2.7.4/libraries/ESP8266httpUpdate/src/ESP8266httpUpdate.h#L52), and like they said, it is not an [HTTP status code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-6.1.1),  it is just a value used by the ESP8266httpUpdate library.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the address of `bin` and `TXT` file by finding the download link of those files form the GitHub. And it has been working by changing the `blob` part of address to `raw`, so the bin address changed form `https://github.com/soheilpaper/ota_github_blink/blob/main/BlinkWithoutDelay_ino_esp8285.bin` to `https://github.com/soheilpaper/ota_github_blink/raw/main/BlinkWithoutDelay_ino_esp8285.bin`, also I have **updated** the question and add more details.