# OTA framework update by GitHub server Connection fail error

Tags: web, ota

I have tried to use some OTA programming method by website servers like this method which was not successful and asked [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/80890/error-101-server-did-not-report-size-from-ota-upgrade-framework-via-git-hub?noredirect=1#comment180919_80890). So I have tried the own Arduino library shown below:

and changed the **[ESP OTA GitHub Library example code](https://github.com/yknivag/ESP_OTA_GitHub/blob/master/examples/GitHub_Upgrade/GitHub_Upgrade.ino)** :

[image]

to this kind :

```
/*
  GitHub_Upgrade.ino - Example for ESP library for auto updating code from GitHub releases.
  Created by Gavin Smalley, November 13th 2019.
  Released under the LGPL v2.1.
  It is the author's intention that this work may be used freely for private
  and commercial use so long as any changes/improvements are freely shared with
  the community under the same terms.
*/

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <FS.h>

#ifndef STASSID
#define STASSID "Adsl momo"
#define STAPSK  "xxxxxx"
#endif

// A single, global CertStore which can be used by all
// connections.  Needs to stay live the entire time any of
// the WiFiClientBearSSLs are present.
#include <CertStoreBearSSL.h>
BearSSL::CertStore certStore;

/* Set up values for your repository and binary names */
#define GHOTA_USER "soheilpaper" //"username"
#define GHOTA_REPO "ota_github_blink" //"repository"
#define GHOTA_CURRENT_TAG "2.0"
#define GHOTA_BIN_FILE "BlinkWithoutDelay_ino_esp8285.bin"//"sketchname.ino.d1_mini.bin"
#define GHOTA_ACCEPT_PRERELEASE 2

#include <ESP_OTA_GitHub.h>

void handle_upgade() {
    // Initialise Update Code
    //We do this locally so that the memory used is freed when the function exists.
    ESPOTAGitHub ESPOTAGitHub(&certStore, GHOTA_USER, GHOTA_REPO, GHOTA_CURRENT_TAG, GHOTA_BIN_FILE, GHOTA_ACCEPT_PRERELEASE);
    
    Serial.println("Checking for update...");
    if (ESPOTAGitHub.checkUpgrade()) {
        Serial.print("Upgrade found at: ");
        Serial.println(ESPOTAGitHub.getUpgradeURL());
        if (ESPOTAGitHub.doUpgrade()) {
            Serial.println("Upgrade complete."); //This should never be seen as the device should restart on successful upgrade.
        } else {
            Serial.print("Unable to upgrade: ");
            Serial.println(ESPOTAGitHub.getLastError());
        }
    } else {
        Serial.print("Not proceeding to upgrade: ");
        Serial.println(ESPOTAGitHub.getLastError());
    }
}

void setup() {
    // Start serial for debugging (not used by library, just this sketch).
    Serial.begin(115200);
    
    // Start SPIFFS and retrieve certificates.
    SPIFFS.begin();
    int numCerts = certStore.initCertStore(SPIFFS, PSTR("/certs.idx"), PSTR("/certs.ar"));
    Serial.print(F("Number of CA certs read: "));
    Serial.println(numCerts);
    if (numCerts == 0) {
        Serial.println(F("No certs found. Did you run certs-from-mozill.py and upload the SPIFFS directory before running?"));
        return; // Can't connect to anything w/o certs!
    }

    // Connect to WiFi
    Serial.print("Connecting to WiFi... ");
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    WiFi.begin(STASSID, STAPSK);
    if ((WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)) {
        Serial.print("... ");
    }
    Serial.println();
  
    /* This is the actual code to check and upgrade */
    handle_upgade();
    /* End of check and upgrade code */
  
    // Your setup code goes here

}

void loop () {
    // Your loop code goes here
Serial.println("main loop");
delay (1000);
Serial.println("handle_upgade starting: ...");

 handle_upgade();
 
 Serial.println("handle_upgade ednded: ...");

 delay (1000);


}
```

but I get the connection error:

```
checking for update...
Not proceeding to upgrade: Connection failed
handle_upgade ednded: ...
```

[image]

Again, I get some connection similar error like [my previous question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/80890/error-101-server-did-not-report-size-from-ota-upgrade-framework-via-git-hub?noredirect=1#comment180919_80890).

So I asked it to find some instruction for fixing it, if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't fully understand this, but I haven't read through it completely either.  Given your apparent success in [your other question about "Error 101 Server Did Not Report Size"](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/80890/error-101-server-did-not-report-size-from-ota-upgrade-framework-via-git-hub/80895) is it fair to say that you got past whatever problem you were having here and that this question **can be closed**?